# Hibernate exception :org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Tags: hibernate, exception

I am getting the following error. Not getting clue why is it happening. Also I checked DB it looks fine.

```
Hibernate: select customer0_.CustomerId as CustomerId0_, customer0_.CustomerAlias as Customer2_0_ from FF_REFERENCE.dbo.Customer customer0_ where customer0_.CustomerId=?

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][Sybase JDBC Driver]**Invalid column name: CustomerId0_**
```

My pojo is:

```
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

// Fields

private String customerId;
private String customerAlias;
```

}

hbm is:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.pojo.reference.Customer" table="Customer" >
    <id name="customerId" column ="CustomerId" length="18" />
        <property name="customerAlias" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CustomerAlias" length="18" />
        </property>
```

The query I am using is:

```
public List findByProperty(String propertyName, Object value,String region) {
    try {
        String queryString = "from Customer as model where model."
                + propertyName + "= ?";
        Query queryObject = getSession().createQuery(queryString);
        queryObject.setParameter(0, value);
        return queryObject.list();
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            }
}
```

I am calling using:

```
custDao.findByProperty("customerId", custName, region);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the answer. the deployed war was taking hbm from the wrong place...

Comment: Hi. When you say taking the hbm from the wrong place. Could you elaborate?? because I think I may have the same problem